# EXT Grid panel does not populate data and creates blank rows

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm trying to populate my grid with sample data and all I see is rows being created and no data.
However, the column headers are present.
I tried various steps which were proposed for similar issues and nothing seems to be working.
Any help here would be great.

```
Ext.define('TestModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
id_property: 'test_id',
fields: [
   {name: 'Date', type: 'string'},
   {name: 'Notifications', type: 'string'},
   {name: 'Status',  type: 'string'}
]
});

Ext.define('D.application.component.dataexplorer.ErrNotifGridPanel',{
extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

initComponent: function()
{
    this.currUserId = DesktopConfig.data.items[0].raw.User_Id;

    var defaultModel = [
                        {
                            header: 'Date',
                            dataIndex: 'Msg_Date',
                            sortable: true                        
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'Notifications',
                            dataIndex: 'Content',
                            sortable: false
                        },
                        {
                            header: 'Status',
                            dataIndex: 'Msg_Status',
                            sortable: true,
                            center: true
                        }];

    //Sample Test Data
    var testData = [
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'ERROR'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
            ['16/12/2008 16:45:32', 'fdshfsdhfdsklfhdsfghdsghdsgkhdskdslkvdslkjds', 'WARNING'],
        ];

    // Test Data
    var Store = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
        model:'TestModel',
        data:testData,
        autoLoad:true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
    /*        reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'items'
            } */
        }, 
        storeId: 'testModel'
    });

    var config =
    {
        columns     : defaultModel,
        store       : 'testModel',
        columnLines : true,
        loadMask    : true,
        autoScroll  : true
    };

    Ext.apply(this,config); 
    this.callParent(arguments);
},

onRender: function()
{
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your columns and model fields have different names.

The column `dataIndex` should be mapped to a field `name` in your model.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ex2Le/